# How to Show Last Month Count On bar Graph SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012

This is my Report 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEtc9.jpg)

graph shows the Total of all the employees in a Category within the given date range. We only require the count of last month on the Graph.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Apply a filter to your chart to only include data for the last month.  By applying it to the chart only, you'll still see all of the detail in the tablix.

[Adding filters in SSRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-filter-report-builder-and-ssrs)